# How to determine if my motherboard supports wake-on-LAN?

Tags: ubuntu, motherboard, bios, wake-on-lan

Okay, so I ran the following command:

```
sudo lshw -html > some_file.html
```

and determined the following:

```
id:            core
description:   Motherboard
product:       30D2
vendor:        Quanta
physical id:   0
version:       79.28
serial:        None
```

I went into the BIOS to look for an option to enable wake-on-LAN but found nothing of the sort.

Is it safe to assume that it is enabled by default? How can I figure this information out?

If it helps, I am using Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit.

Comment: This feels like a question more likely to receive a better/faster response on our sister site superuser.com. Would you like me to move it over?

Comment: @Chopper: Sure... I just thought that a network-related question would have a happy home here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [ethtool](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ethtool):

```
sudo ethtool NAME
```

where `NAME` is the name of the ethernet device (probably `eth0`, run `ifconfig` if you aren't sure). The output may include a list of supported wake-on-LAN modes.

The output from `lshw` may already include the information you need, in the capabilities attribute. It's probably under the node for your ethernet card. It may also be listed under the firmware or BIOS nodes.